# using isalpha and toupper together in while loop gives "index out of bounds"

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

This is the code that gives the error of `"index -65 out of bounds for type 'int [26]'"`

```
char x;
int a[26] = {0};

printf("Enter first word: ");
while ((x=(isalpha(toupper(getchar())))) != '\n')
{
    a[x-'A']++;
}
```

whereas if I change it to this

```
char x;
int a[26] = {0};

printf("Enter first word: ");
while ((x=((toupper(getchar()))) != '\n')

    if (isalpha(x))
    {
        a[x-'A']++ ;
    }
```

It behaves as wanted, the error gone.
What am I doing wrong in the first one that results in the error ?

Comment: Alright, I've done as you said. But why remove the toupper and isalpha tags ? Were they misleading ?

Comment: Consider that `isalpha` is likely to return a boolean value (1 or a 0, though the 1 could be any non-zero value). When you subtract 26 from that, you'll get a negative value. A negative value as an index for an array is not a good sign...

Comment: You may also want to think about in which world `isalpha(anything)` is likely to equal `'\n'`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says `index -65`, so `x-'A'` in `a[x-'A']` must be -65. The ASCII value of `'A'` is 65, giving `x-65 = -65`, which resolves as `x = 0`.

Why is `x = 0`?

Because `x` is the result of `isalpha`, which returns a boolean value. In particular, it returns `0` for *false*.

Also, it makes no sense to compare this boolean value to `'\n'`.

Did you mean

```
while (isalpha(x = toupper(getchar())))
```

?

Note that your code doesn't handle `EOF` correctly, though. `EOF` is not a `char`, which is why `getchar` returns `int`. Assigning its result to `x` loses information.

Comment: The value yielded by `isalpha` for "true" may be any non-zero integer